# Update to use previous row's value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a  Table which has the following columns  Date, Ticker, Return. I would like to add a new column to the table "Price_Computed" where Price_Computed starts with a value of 100 for the first date and then it is calculated as follows Price_Computed  =  Price_Computed(PreviousDate) * Return from current date
Please see attached screenshot.

Example

[image]

I am using SQL Server 2019 and out of sorts on how to go about this.
Thank you.

Comment: This looks like running total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a recursive subquery:

```
with t as (
      select date, ticker, return, 100 as value,
             row_number() over (partition by ticker order by date) as seqnum
      from table t
     ),
     cte as (
      select date, ticker, return, value, seqnum
      from t
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select t.date, t.ticker, t.return, cte.value * (1 + t.return), t.seqnum
      from cte join
           t
           on t.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select *
from cte;
```

What you really need is a cumulative product function.  SQL Server does not have one built-in.  You can mimic one using logs and exponents; however, I find that errors accumulate rather quickly with such an approach.

Comment: when I run this , I get an "Recursive common table expression 'cte' does not contain a top-level UNION ALL operator" ?

Comment: @dman . . . That is a big oversight.  I wonder if I deleted accidentally when I posted the answer.

Comment: thank you! I appreciate it!  I had to make two modifications 1.)  in the anchor query add seqnum for union all  2.) I had 12million rows so i needed to set to infinite recursion